# JSF file upload method not found

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to implement single file upload. Here is my code:

```
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="mainHeader">Settings</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h:outputLabel value="Upload FIle"></h:outputLabel>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button"> 
                                        <h:inputFile value="#{fileBean.file}" >
                                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>
                                                <f:ajax execute="@all" render="@form" listener="#{fileBean.parseDoc}"/>
                                                <span>Upload</span>
                                        </h:inputFile>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h:commandButton actionListener="#{fileBean.parseDoc}"></h:commandButton>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </h:form>
```

And here is the bean:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FileBean {
    private Part file;



    public void parseDoc(){
        Ivy.log().debug("Size is: "+file.getSize());
    }


    public Part getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(Part file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

Each time I invoke the method parseDoc it throws this error:

```
MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: FileBean@8cace1c.parseDoc(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)
```

I dont really know what is the problem here as the naming seems to be okay with the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error you can see that JSF is looking for a method with the signature: `parseDoc(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)`. Your method does not take a parameter and thus is not valid. Just add a parameter of type `javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent` to your `parseDoc()` method.